# Find the values of $c$ for which the vectors make an obtuse angle for any $x{\epsilon}(0,\infty)$

Tags: inequality, vectors, logarithms, quadratics

Find the values of $c$ for which the vectors $\vec a=(c\log_2x) \hat i-6\hat j+3\hat k$ and $\vec b=(\log_2x)\hat i-2\hat j+(2c\log_2x)\hat k$ make an obtuse angle for any $x {\epsilon} (0,\infty)$

I found out the dot product, and found $cos\theta<0$, whereby I got a quadratic inequality. Since, the inequality was less than zero, I used the discriminant as not having any solution to find the value of $c \epsilon (0,\frac{4}{3})$. However, the answer did not match, and I am a bit confused. Please help.

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: The answer is $(-\frac{4}{3},0)$

Comment: I think the answer is wrong. If we take $c=-1$, which is in the region you gave, then we have $$\cos\theta=\frac{-[\log_2x]^2-6[\log_2x]+12}{\text{something positive}}.$$
But the quadratic $-Y^2-6Y+12=0$ has distinct roots, which means the quadratic can take positive values. Something's not right...

Comment: I feel the same, that's the reason I am a bit confused.

Comment: Yeah, unless I've made a silly mistake I think the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Teddy38 that is true, however, my doubt is, if $c>0$ then the above equation turns out to be positive for $x\epsilon (1,\infty)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$\cos(\phi)=\frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|}$$
so we get
$$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=c(\log_2 x)^2+12+6c\log_2 x$$ can you finish?
the discriminat is $$9-\frac{12}{c}$$ it must be $$9-\frac{12}{c}<0$$ and we get
$$0<c<\frac{4}{3}$$
as you stated

Comment: I got this exactly, and since $cos\phi<0$ , I solved the discriminant and my solution for $c$ came out to be $(0,\frac{4}{3})$. P.S. I took $D<0$

Comment: you solved it for $c$?

Comment: Yes sir. I did, and found the above answer. I would request you to verify if you are getting the same as me.

Comment: So, I guess the given answer $-\frac{4}{3}<c<0$ is incorrect?

Comment: if we assume $$c<0$$ so we get $$c>\frac{4}{3}$$ this is impossible, yes